# Tango Unity example point cloud scripts not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, google-project-tango, point-clouds

I'm currently experimenting on the Tango point cloud scripts.

I used Tango Camera and attached TangoARScreen script to it, I have also enabled depth and video overlay in Tango Manager prefab. The Tango Point Cloud prefab is in the scene as well.

I have experimented with the Tango Floor Finding script with this setting. However, after pressing 'find floor', the scene is stuck on the searching message, and couldn't detect any floor or show any markers.

I also experimented with the placing kitty script, this time it can detect the floor but the kitty is placed slightly higher than the real floor. I replaced the place kitty script by creating a plane, then this plane is shown much higher than the real floor.

I have tried to print out the y value of the depth, it would give a reasonable result such as -0.95, but what it is shown on the screen is nowhere near the real floor.

Is this my device problem(I'm using the tablet) or there is something wrong with my AR screen script(I'm using the default TangoARScreen)?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried building the `TangoFloorFinding` scene provided in the project? You might be missing some script or a prefab.